# counting rows of selected data in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm going to count returned rows by this query:

```
 select * from tableName where( number > 1000);
```

I tried this query to get rows count:

```
 select count(*) as count from (select * from tableName where( number > 1000));
```

but I got syntax error. What is wrong with that?

Comment: remove as count or use different keyword than count as cont

Comment: `select count(*) as cnt from tableName where( number > 1000);`

Comment: there is no need for you to do a nested query. YOu can get the desired result by removing that. Just put your condition in where clause ( number >1000 )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works if you are using nested query & don't use 'count' as your temporary variable name:

```
select count(temp.id) as num from (select * from tableName where number > 1000) temp
```

Answer (score 4):

You dont want Nested Query Just Use

```
select count(*) as count from tableName where number > 1000 ;
```

Comment: using sql reserved words (count) is not recommended

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne: just to clarify: **`COUNT`** is *not* a MySQL reserved word. (My preference would be avoid using it as a column alias, since it does match the name of a MySQL function; but it is valid to use `COUNT` as a column alias.)

Comment: As per i know count is a function not a keyword.  there are some reserved words i encountered problem date once.

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this

```
select count(*) as noOfCount from tableName where number > 1000;
```

Do not use sql reserved keywords as your temp variable names

Answer (score 1):

Why not counting the rows in 1 select directly:

```
select count(*) from tableName where number>1000;
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it simple. Don't need a subquery

```
select count(*) as count from tableName where number > 1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

Likely, the syntax error your are getting is "every derived table must have an alias".

To fix that syntax error, you would just assign an alias to the inline view query.

```
SELECT foo FROM (SELECT foo FROM bar) a ;
                                      ^
```

---

But for your specific query, an inline view isn't required.

You could simply modify your original query, to replace the `*` in the SELECT list with an aggregate expression such as `COUNT(*)`. You can also assign an alias to the aggregate expression.

It's valid to use `COUNT` as a column alias, but my preference would be to use a different alias, one that isn't the name of a MySQL function.

Answer (score 0):

FIrst thing first

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as tot_rows FROM `tableName` WHERE  `number` > 1000 ;
```

you better give back tilt (`) sign arond number, cause might be there's a keyword in mysql called number. I am not pretty sure, but you should take precaution.

Second you can do another thing also.

If you are using PHP then

```
$query_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tableName` WHERE  `number` > 1000");

$num_row = mysql_numrows($query_result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This query works fine

select count(*) as count from tableName where number > 1000 ;

but FYR in ur query error is u don't define subquery name in example its tbl

select count(*) as count from (select * from tableName where( number > 1000)) as tbl;